# Gradle builld takes too long

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have problem with gradle build, each time when I run my application it take more than one minute too build app. I already turn on

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

this is my gradle project in Gradle project (Android Studio)

[image: Gradle project]

Can somebody help me to find problem ?

Comment: When I look at gradle task list there is two tasks :app:processDevelopReleaseResources and :app:processDevelopDebugResources , executing this two take 90% of whole build .

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462761/why-my-gradle-building-taking-too-much-time/40482267#40482267) might be help for you.

Answer (score 1):

It may be for the version of Android Studio you are using. Make sure that you are using the latest version 2.0.0. go to build>make project in your toolbar.

Comment: My current version of Android studio is 2.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are building 4 versions now:

1. Develop debug
2. Develop release
3. Production debug
4. Production release

To speed it up, just build the one version you want to run.

Comment: How I can choose to build just one version, to start assembleDevelop task ?

Comment: From the command line you'd do: `./gradlew assembleDevelop`. In Android Studio, you'd probably need to edit the run configuration settings.

Comment: I try this but the result is same.