# Why my gradle building taking too much time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing the app which has apk size 28 MB. What should I do so that I take less time.

If I run on emulator than it takes 5-7 mins but if I run it on device than it is taking more than 10 min.

Comment: it takes time to upload the data and to on the device...

Comment: is there any way to reduce time  @Shivam

Comment: go to toolbar >> Refactor >> Remove Unused Resources.. this will help you a bit.. in reducing the app size and to build fast

Comment: @Ankur: Check logs of gradle build and see which task is taking time. Is your app has multiple flavors?

Comment: Enable instant run,Offline Mode

Comment: Android Monitor-: logcat?? @SagarTrehan

Comment: it will delete comment data also @Shivam

Comment: no it wont delete the comment data

Comment: @Ankur: Start build and watch "Gradle Console" output. You can check which task is taking time. Not logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set ***file->setting->search 'Gradle'-> check 'use local gradle distribution' and check 'offline work'***.. in android studio. it will improve gradel building time.

**Note**: In newer version of Android studio, `View->Tool Windows->Gradle->Toggle button of online/offline`

Comment: No help.. getting same time.

Comment: then may be your system configuration is low. and android studio required more RAM min 4 gb. if you have 8gb then its better. and processor more then core-i5.

Comment: system configuration:- 8GB RAM and core- i5

Comment: i also facing this same issue. when i start computer at morning its work fine for 3 4 hour. but after that its taking too much time for gradle building. may be need to format pc or change hdd to ssd hard disk. i have also same configuration as you mention.

Comment: somewhere i here that. if we have SSd hard disk then its work too much fast for any kind of processing.  work fast on speed of 10x compare to hdd.

Comment: if build is taking more than 30min,  try **gradle offline mode** .   android_studio 3.6 and above   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6

Answer (score 2):

There are some tips for reducing your build time:
In your `/.gradle/gradle.properties` file :

```
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
org.gradle.daemon=true
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

And you can disable the lint task when you build your project,add the task in your build.gradle file:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

It is really useful for me! Hope it can help you!

Before reducing the building time, you should find out which step cost too much time.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --dry-run --profile
```

It will product a report about the work of building in `build/reports/profile/` direction, just read the report then to optimize your build work.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue, what i had done was disabling instant run in the project settings, and rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on Windows, then you should open `Control Panel` -> `Windows Defender`, then go to `Settings` -> `Excluded Files and Locations` -> `Browse`, and add your project library (including the `build` folder), and `C:\Users\YourUser\.gradle`

---

Also, add following to `gradle.properties` in your project:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
```

Comment: Then try the second option

Comment: No help.. getting same time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just landed here recently and the above solutions:

- Increase memory
- Put Gradle in offline mode
- Tweak Gradle settings

and you are still suffering a very slow building (usually the first one), and you are using Windows OS, I suggest you try to temporarily disable the Real-Time Protection system from Windows Defender until it finishes the building.

It is very snoopy regarding processes that download files and can interfere with Gradle building.

Of course... be careful if the project you are building is not coming from a trustworthy source... use this tip at your own risk.
Since the first building is usually when you are kickstarting a new project, it should be safe enough.