# Cannot enable Gradle's offline mode on Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.6

I'm using the new **Android Studio 3.6 Canary 9** to test new functionalities, and I cannot enable Gradle's offline mode.

[image]

In Android Studio Preferences window, tab Gradle, I cannot find the entry point to enable it. Is this a bug or Google has disabled Gradle's offline mode?

Note that `--offline` option is still working when using command line.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

From the Android Studio 3.6 new features blog post:

> New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode
> To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

[Here is the link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui)

Comment: But this new entry point is bad compared to the old checkbox. It does not **explicit** showing that the "offline mode" is enabled or not. The **highlight state** is enabled, isn't it?

Comment: True stable recently. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: I set it to offline mode and restarted and sync gradle again but I am still getting the errors mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393227/gradle-sync-failed-android-studio-3-6 please help.

Comment: To all the confused souls. It is offline mode when the toggle button is highlighted. 

Comment: Poor UX design. Developers are in confusion while the pressed state is online or offline.

Comment: Many thanks for the information of the new location of the offline mode. In my case though it does not help. The only guarantee to speed up gradle is to turn off wifi. A little disappointing matter.

Answer (score 50):

To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, select `View > Tool Windows > Gradle` from the menu bar and near the top of the Gradle window, click `Toggle Offline Mode` [image: Gradle] 
[image]

Comment: I believe many will not understand what this icon mean poor icon UX here

Comment: you can always use material design plugin it appears as a wifi icon

Comment: So when is offline mode enabled? When highlighted not when not highlighted? I'm confused

Comment: this is a very hard button to find. if it wasn't for this post I wouldn't have found the button

Comment: Very poor UX design. Developers are in confusion that the pressed state is offline or online.

Answer (score 36):

To clarify it. In your ***Android Studio...***

> View > Tool Windows > Gradle

And then this...

[image]

And this...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Many people have given correct answer, I am just adding pictures relevant to Android Studio 3.6.2.  When I upgraded to Android Studio 3.6.2 I kept getting error while doing build that 'Gradle was in offline mode' but under File>Settings>Gradle> I could not see the option to switchoff Gradle offline mode. So I did a fresh install of Android Studio 3.6.2 and I continued to get the same problem. After checking various answers I found that the placement of Gradle offline switch has changed & you can do the switch in Gradle panel as per the 2nd image below.

Image1-[image: Android Studio3.6.2 does not have Gradle Offline Switch in this location]
Image2- [image]

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below steps :
1.Open Your project.
2.Go to the Left side of the Gradle button.
3. 
[image]
4.Click button above image show .
5. if this type of view you are not in offline mode.
6. Go to Build and rebucild the project.

All above point is work for me.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
**To enable offline mode you can follow below steps:**

```
1. Click "Gradle" on the right corner
2. Click button "Toggle offline mode" to disable
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Flutter Projects**

You **WON'T** find this option (`View  > Tool Windows > Gradle`)

[image]

Spent hours trying to find it.

You have to open your Android project in another Android Studio window.

Go to `Open` and select the Android project:

[image]

When the new window opens, follow the recommended step and voila:

[image]

You can now find the Gradle view window to the right.

When working with Flutter, this is how you make Gradle specific changes.

Answer (score 1):

Oh in the last release of the android studio the location of the `offline mode` option has changed!

But it is so easy to just click on Gradle on the right side of the android studio or (go to `View >  Tools windows and select Gradle`! )

and Like a photo Turn on or Turn off the Wifi Icon :

[image]

Comment: Which version of Android Studio that you are using? It's strange

Comment: 3.6! stable channel! I have Material theme On my android studio  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8oizn7DDaY&list=PLcP-of83VmheRYTAMmFKufZSIlcdbeU2i&index=7&t=0s

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.6, You can toggle Gradle from offline to online mode (See screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1MhE.png)) and hit Gradle sync. This solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

After Update Go To File >> Project Structure >> Suggestions and on the Right side pane Click update