# android studio 3.6 how to set gradle offline

Tags: android, gradle, offline

there is no switch in gradle setting of AS version 3.6

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot enable Gradle's offline mode on Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6)

Answer (score 5):

[You can find the information here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#gradle-offline-ui)

It is written there:

> To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel