# Gradle Sync Failed Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, offline-mode, android-studio-3.6

I have just updated the Android Studio from 3.5.3 to 3.6. After this update, I have updated the Gradle and Android SDK Build Tools as well. Now the Gradle sync is failing with these errors:

```
1. org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
    Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
 2. org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not
    resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.
 3. org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached
    version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0 available for
    offline mode.
```

Looking at the 3rd error it seems that **Offline Work** option needs to be disabled in Android Studio **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle**. But the **Offline Work** check box is no where to be found in the said settings.
Is it the actual problem? If yes, then how it could be disabled in **Android Studio 3.6**? If no, then what is the problem here?

I have already tried **Invalidate Caches / Restart** but it did not help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Run to the very same error a while ago. This worked for me.

*From the Android Studio 3.6 new features blog post: New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel*

Source: [Cannot enable Gradle's offline mode on Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6)

Comment: Thank you this problem was terribly getting into my nerves.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue and deleting **".idea"** folder inside project directory and deleting **".gradle"** directory from home helped me resolve the issue.