# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello guys currently iam facing with this issue . What should i do to resolve it.

```
internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
```

Comment: A similar issue has been solved here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399107/7447262)

Comment: I found the solution for this issue ...