# This is related to android studio ide problem, after update our ide

Tags: java, android-studio-3.6

when I updated my ide and opened a new basic activity then it is not working and giving the message that" design editor is not available" on the screen and on the downside window the message" No cache version of com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode" is showing.

and these all are blocking my activity_main window to design and make the layout of the app and also I am not getting the "text" and "design" window of my activity_main window.

Comment: and for this I searched you-tube they talked there about some process and I had done that even after that I am facing such problems

Answer (score 0):

No cache version of com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode - this message is shown when working in offline. This is resolved by connecting to network. If you want to work in offline mode Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798122/8636351)!

I am not getting the "text" and "design" 
 - This is the latest update and you can switch across text, view, text/view. **Top right corner there is option to switch across.**

Here's [a link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36.html[image])!