# Disable Gradle Offline mode in Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I updated my Android Studio application to the latest version on Mac to Android Studio 3.6, Build: **#AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805**

I saw the option to enable offline mode(in the Build output area or so) when the build failed due to Internet connection problems and I did so by clicking the supplied link.

Later on, I needed to disable offline mode and I followed the normal steps:

Go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.

But on the Gradle option in this very build, there was no **Check the Offline work checkbox**

My question is:

**How do I disable offline mode under the newest build of Android Studio?**

Comment: i was also facing this problem after update.
but now my problem has been solved

Comment: how i solved the problem, visit and watch...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVBi6J9ygNE

Comment: if you have yet any question yet please reply me ASAP.

Comment: I will watch and revert. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the answer in English? your video pointed me in the right direction, but the language barrier meant I had to figure out the rest by myself.

I have it working now. If you post the answer here in English, I will accept it.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Check out this video.
https://youtu.be/DBEa1-a8uAEn

@gbenroscience

Comment: Alright, can you post an answer now? I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208836/discussion-between-mufazmi-and-gbenroscience).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot enable Gradle's offline mode on Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6)

Answer (score 17):

The **Same answer** as above but in **pictures**.

Look at the **right side** of the Android studio, you will see **gradle** tab. Click on it.

[image]

[image]

**If you cannot see gradle tab then**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! its already been resolved though. An upvote for the concern is in order!