# this is error display when run project (i made unenable offline mode ) and use gradle 3.6.1 or 3.3.2 but display this is problem

Tags: android-studio, gradle-plugin, offline-mode, aapt2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Gradle Offline mode in Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475046/disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio-3-6)

Comment: @ebtsammuhammed did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is may be a duplicate question,

but still you can use this method to solve this issue.

> select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the
>   top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline
>   button in the Gradle panel.

And run your code again.

This step will fixed your issue.

Thanks

[All the process is in .gif format for easily understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnfsC.gif)

Comment: l made this step fixed  but still error display

Comment: @ebtsammuhammed how did you fix the error?