# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio

I search my problem and find this answer ([Disable Gradle Offline mode in Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475046/disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio-3-6))
which doesnt help.can any one help me??

this is the Error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.1-6040484/aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Add mavenCentral() in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```