# Android Studio offline option is not showing up

Tags: android, android-studio

I faced following issue, so I needed to uncheck offline option in Android Studio but my offline option is not there, I am also attaching the screenshot and 3 errors. My android studio version is 3.6.1

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
```

**Second:**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
```

**Third:**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3 available for offline mode.
```

[image: no-offline]

Comment: refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android Studio 3.6 new features blog post:

New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button

Or try with offline icon[image]

Comment: where is Gradle window?