# How to solve this error of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2 available for offline mode.

This is my error and I don't know how to solve this please help me to solve this

Comment: Delete your .idea/ and .gradle/ folder, disable offline mode and resync your project. Your project is trying to fetch a dependency it doesn't have while you're offline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245718/6021469 to disable offline mode

Comment: couldn't resolve

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio select

```
View > Tool Windows > Gradle
```

from the menu bar.Here On the top of the Gradle window ,click on **Toggle Offline Mode**  button in the Gradle window.
[image: Image attached]