# Android Studio 3.6: Gradle "Offline Mode" is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an unstable internet connection so i want to work in **Offline Mode**.
I build my project with internet connection and then turn on the **Offline Mode**. *I did not change anything*, but the build fails telling me some dependency that i don't have in my *Gradle* files is not cached.

```
No cached version listing for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) available for offline mode.
```

I even added this in my dependencies but it didn't work.
I guess that Gradle does not cache all the dependency tree but only the direct dependencies.

Is there a way to manually download these packages and copy to Gradle cache?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look on this stack query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6#:~:text=From%20the%20Android%20Studio%203.6,button%20in%20the%20Gradle%20panel

Comment: Thanks.But I have no problem with the UI. The problem is that some of the packages are not cached automatically so, the Offline Mode would not work as promised.